# Service Authorization with Dependency Injection in Web API 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have an n-tiered web api 2 project that is structured as such:

1. Web Layer
2. Service/Business Layer
3. Data/Repository Layer

The web controllers have the corresponding service injected with Autofac and each service has the corresponding repository injected.  This works fine.

Now, I am needing to inject an object that has some information about the user for business logic purposes.  Similar to this:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private readonly IOrderRepo _Repo;
    private readonly EnterpriseUser _EnterpriseUser;

    public OrderService(IOrderRepo repo, EnterpriseUser enterpriseUser)
    {
        this._Repo = repo;
        this._EnterpriseUser = enterpriseUser;
    }
    ....
}
```

The user information is needed for things such as if they are a certain privilege level then their orders may be placed in a queue to be reviewed by an administrator or they may receive a discount.

My issue arises with the Authentication process.  The `EnterpriseUser` requires a claim from the current `IIdentity`.

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
    // Identity extension to retrieve claim from User
    var userLinkCode = ctx.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().User.Identity.GetUserLinkCode();
    // Retrieves a header from the request
    var partnerLinkCode = ctx.Resolve<ConnectionInfo>().PartnerLinkCode;
    return EnterpriseUser.Create(userLinkCode, partnerLinkCode);
})
.As<EnterpriseUser>()
.InstancePerRequest();
```

So when the user's token has expired, Autofac will throw the following exception

> A delegate registered to create instances of 'LVV.Services.EnterpriseUser' returned null

because the Claims are empty and the `AuthorizeAttribute` is never able to reject the call with `401 Unauthorized` since the controller's constructor runs before the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Is there known work around for this?

Possibly a way to reject the call with `401` if the delegate returns null?

Or a better way to inject information about the user to the service layer, while still allowing for the OAuth authentication process to function.

Comment: Could you please provide code of `EnterpriseUser` registraction?

Comment: @KozhevnikovDmitry I have added the registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to implement [NullObject pattern](https://hackernoon.com/why-you-need-null-object-pattern-and-how-to-implement-it-16a96b04125f) here to let `AuthorizeAttribute` do its job and not confuse Autofac and contructors with raw null values. I don't see your entire code, so the example below is just an illustration of the idea. Let's say that we extend `EnterpriseUser` in this way:

```
public class EnterpriseUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Always true for real user
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsAuthentificated => true;

    public static EnterpriseUser Create(string userLinkCode, string partnerLinkCode)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLinkCode) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(partnerLinkCode))
        {
            return new DummyEnterpriseUser();
        }

        // create true user here with usin link codes
        return new EnterpriseUser(userLinkCode, partnerLinkCode);
    }

    // Some usefull code here
}


/// <summary>
/// NullObject implementation for <see cref="EnterpriseUser"/>
/// </summary>
public class DummyEnterpriseUser : EnterpriseUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Always false for dummy user
    /// </summary>
    public override bool IsAuthentificated => false;

    public DummyEnterpriseUser()
    {

    }
}
```

`IsAuthentificated` flag was added just in case, you probably wouldn't need it. I also assumed that your extension method `GetUserLinkCode` returns `null` in case of empty claims. The final implementation will depend of your code of course.

Comment: Wow, that is so simple and elegant!

Comment: Happy to help=)